# How to pass ng-models to a form

Tags: angularjs

i have a form with two differently named ng-models. I need to pass both of them with the form. How would this work? I need to pass `currentItem + currentItem.Customer` I am having trouble with a PdfSharp controller and I want to see if this is the reason why the Customer Values are being passed back as Null.

controller

```
  $scope.EmailPdf = function () {

   var id = $scope.currentItem.JobId
    $http.get('/api/Pdf/' + id).success(function () {
        $scope.PrintPreviewModal();
    });
}
```

form

```
    <form ng-submit="submitJob()" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm">
  <fieldset>
   <div class="col-xs-12">
   <label>Number:</label>
    <input ng-model="currentItem.JobNumber" type="text" name="JobNumber">
    <label>Customer:</label>
    <input  type="text" ng-model="currentItem.Customer.CustomerName"
      typeahead="customer.CustomerName for customer in customerArray | filter:$viewValue"
       typeahead-on-select="selectEditCustomer($item)">
       </div>
       <input ng-model="currentItem.CustomerId" type="text" ng-hide="true"/>
       <div class="inline-fields">
       <label >Status:</label>
       <selectng-model="currentItem.JobStatus">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="Active">Active</option>
        <option value="InActive">InActive</option>
        <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
        </select>
       <label>Address:</label>
       <input  ng-model="currentItem.Customer.CustomerAddress" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="inline-fields">
       <label>Name:</label>
       <input ng-model="currentItem.JobName" type="text">
        <label>City:</label>
        <input ng-model="currentItem.Customer.CustomerCity" type="text">
       <label>St:</label>
         <inputng-model="currentItem.Customer.CustomerState" type="text">

          <label>Zip:</label>
         <input ng-model="currentItem.Customer.CustomerZipcode" type="text">
         </div>
          <div class="inline-fields">
           <label>Address:</label>
           <input ng-model="currentItem.JobAddress" type="text">
           <label>Ph:</label>
           <input ng-model="currentItem.Customer.CustomerPhoneNumber" type="text">

            <label>Fax:</label>
           <input disabled style="width: 105px"ng-model="currentItem.Customer.CustomerFaxNumber" type="text">
            </div>


         <input ng-click="EmailPdf(currentItem)" type="button" value="Email"  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's a bit difficult to tell exactly what you are asking here, but it sounds like you mean that you need to pass more information than the ID into your get. So you can pass the entire currentItem with all it's content like this

```
         $http.get('/api/Pdf/' + id,angular.toJson($scope.currentItem)).....
```

Is that what you are trying to do?